# Anyway to send HTML to Pa11y for logged in pages?

Tags: pa11y

Working on a Chrome extension, and I want one click checking for logged-in pages, rather than asking a (non-technical) user to send pa11y the selectors for login, if I were to harvest the HTML and send it to a server to run a pa11y scan, would this work?  I supposed I'd need the CSS too?  If not this approach, is there any other approach to scan "this" page without so a non-technical user can just click a button and see the results on a logged in page?

Answer (score 0):

Pa11y is basically a CLI wrapper for HTML_Codesniffer. It sounds like your needs would be better served using the HTML_Codesniffer bookmarklet directly.

You can send your non-technical user the link to the HTML_Codesniffer bookmarklet here: https://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/